# How to set Priority of IntentService in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, service, thread-priority

I was wondering if it is possible to set the priority of an `IntentService` like you can with a `Thread`. So far I have not found anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `HandlerThread` that `IntentService` uses is not exposed to the SDK. It is set to `Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_DEFAULT` as a priority.

Note that `IntentService` is 143 lines of code, including whitespace and comments, so you might consider just cloning it to have one with the priority you seek.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Thats actually what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 13):

You can set `Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND)` in the `onHandleIntent()` method of your intent service.

The solution by CommonsWare also works. This one is simpler, though.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clear - by default `IntentService` priority is default- `Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_DEFAULT` because it uses `HandlerThread` Internally. You can use `Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND)` in OnHandleIntent(), or whatever the CommonsWare suggested in the answer.

some people raised this as [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35440). and there is also [patch](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/41820/) available for this.

Answer (score -4):

I changed the IntentService's priority using: 
"android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);"
in the constructor of the IntentService class.

In my case it was changed from:
"Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_DEFAULT" which is zero (0) to
"Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND" which is ten (10) and the result was visible.

Comment: You are changing the priority of the thread that creates the IntentService, not the priority of the thread were the handler lives. See the accepted answer for more information.