# How to set the priority of android service?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

Is there any way to set the priority of android service? I want to run the service in background after destroying App's main actvity. So i am returning "START_REDELIVERY_INTENT" from my service. But restarting of service is taking some time (around 1-3 minutes). I want to restart the service instantly. Is there any way to set the priority of android service.

FYI, I am creating service using startService and passing an object through intent.putExtra().

Below snapshot is taken from setting/apps/running apps by my android device, which shows that app is restarting... My app is real time specific, so i want to restart it instantly...

[image]

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3622139/2591002)  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot control this behavior of `Service` as it depends on the OS and available resources. However, for a continuously running background service, I would suggest you to return `START_STICKY` - which tries its best to re-run the service once its destroyed due to any reasons.

Comment: But I need to pass an object to my service and only possible way to pass the previously delivered intent (during desroying main activity) is "START_REDELIVER_INTENT" (as per my knowledge)... Is there any other solution?

Comment: Other ways to do it is to use serializable and write object state, but my object is of class "BluetoothDevice" which i cant serialize... only way to serialize is to save the device address and device name and search & match it back while restarting... So there will be so many issues of synchronization and time constraints... I am looking for some simpler way... If u have? Thanx in advance :)

Comment: BluetoothDevice implements Parcelable, hence you can marshal its data into bytes and may reuse it later after reconstruction. However, when dealing with BluetoothDevice, you may simply preserve address and name - as you also said so. Sometimes there are simple solutions to a problem which we just overlook.

Comment: Yups i did it!!! I returned "START_STICKY" in my service so it is restarting INSTANTLY (which i actually want)... I saved device address into file using filehandling and retrive it from file while restarting the service... Restrating the service i checked, if intent is null... Code working fine... For making BluetoothDevice object from device address (String form), i used "device = myBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(device_address);"

Answer (score 3):

The priority depends on the component type and the current app that the user is using. The highest priority have the current `Activity` that is displayed to the user and all [foreground services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground). Foreground services must have a notification that cannot be dismissed. To create a foreground service you have to call `startForeground(...)` method from the `Service` itself passing the id of the notification and the `Notification` object itself. You can use the id if you want to update the notification later.

I recommend you to make the [service bound](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) and bind your activity to the service. This way the you can start and stop the service in your `onResume` and `onPause` methods.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to increase service priority in this case is to make it a [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground).